# How do I determine the variance of a collection of groups?

Tags: variance, pooling

I’m trying to compute the variance of how much pumpkins weigh across pumpkins from 125 farms. However, I only have, for each farm, three pieces of data: (1) the variance of weights for pumpkins from that farm (2) how many pumpkins the farm has (3) the total weight of the pumpkins from the farm.

How can I compute a “weighted variance” of how much a pumpkin weighs across farms? Can I just compute a weighted average of the individual variances?

Comment: I hope you also have information about the weights in each farm--either total or average--for that is needed to obtain an answer.

Comment: Hmm, ok, lets assume that I also have the total weight in each farm.

Comment: This sounds like the question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43159 on computing pooled variances but with $2$ groups replaced by $125$. Is that correct?  If so, it may be worth observing that the solution there extends directly (and in the obvious manner) to your situation.