# Calculate variance of subpopulation given variance of overall population and its complement

Tags: variance, sum

I'd like to be able to calculate the sample variance for a subpopulation [B]  given the sample mean and variance for its complement [A] and the overall population [A+B].

I have the sample mean and variance for

- Overall population [A+B]
- Subpopulation [A]

I know I can calculate the mean for B as:

```
  mean[B] = ( mean[A+B] * (n[A] + n[B]) - mean[A] * n[B]) / nB
```

But I don't know if it's easy to calculate the sample variance for the complement in a similar way.

Comment: Ah, I think it's rearranging teh final line of this answer to solve for s2[n+1:n+m]    http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43159/how-to-calculate-pooled-variance-of-two-groups-given-known-group-variances-mean?rq=1

Comment: vB  = ((v0 + m0*m0)*n0 - (vA + mA*mA)*nA)/nB -  mB*mB;