# How to pool more than two sample means and standard deviations?

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-mixture-distribution, pooling

I have 4 independent samples from one population, with their respective sample sizes, means and standard deviations. I don't have the raw data, and all of them follow gaussian distributions.

- Sample 1: n1=5, mean1=183, sd1=24
- Sample 2: n2=10, mean2=170, sd2=20
- Sample 3: n3=19, mean3=165, sd3=21
- Sample 4: n4=20, mean4=117, sd4=13

How can I calculate the average of all of them (four samples) and obtain the resulted normal distribution (which would be number 5)? It would be represented by its new sample size, mean and sd.

Comment: What do you mean by "normal distribution" and how is "number 5" related to these statistics you quote?

Comment: The four samples (1,2,3,4) distributed normally. How can I average the four samples? I mean, I would like to obtain the mean of the four means and the mean of the sds. I don't know whether I am clarifying my question...

Comment: Yes, the question is clearer now.  Use the methods described at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43159/how-to-calculate-pooled-variance-of-two-groups-given-known-group-variances-mean.  However, your statistics demonstrate conclusively that these ssamples are *not* independent samples of the same population: the differences among their means are enormously significant. This calls into question what kind of data you are really dealing with and what you actually want to accomplish. Maybe there's a typographical error?  Perhaps mean4 is $171$ instead of $117$?

Comment: In fact, it is not a typographical error. These samples measure the same variable in four different modern human populations, so they are all grouped within Homo sapiens. Thanks for the link whuber. How could it be possible to the mixture of my four samples?

Comment: Since they are samples from four different populations, not one, may I ask what the intended interpretation of the pooled statistics would be? It wouldn't tell you much about the superpopulation (of all humans) because the values would be weighted by sample size rather than population size.

Comment: The issue is that I would like to compare the four samples as a whole (i.e. combining them) in order to compare with other species, as Neandertals. Although I have just compared each modern human sample with Neandertals, I would like to have a "superpopulation" of Homo sapiens in order to compare it.

Comment: That's a different question. Pooling these statistics would not give you accurate information about the superpopulation. (A simple analog would be if you had a sample of five women and, separately, a sample of 15 men and therefore concluded that people are 75% male.) You could do a weighted pooling, but the wisdom of that is dubious because it is already clear that the superpopulation is not homogeneous, calling into question the meaningfulness of comparing it to another population in terms of an overall mean and standard deviation.

Comment: I understand what you mean. However, is there any possibility to calculate the mean of the means and the mean of the standard deviations of the four samples? I note that it would be important to weight each sample depending on their sample sizes, right?